# Datatable fixedcolumns 'no records' message

Tags: jquery, datatable

Is it possible render empty table message not in 'main' columns but in fixed columns instead?? any workaround?
Found actual problem. 'padding-left' for leftColumns it dataTable_empty will be cloned with this but this is out of frame fixed columns so in FixedColumns config

```
            drawCallback: function (left) {
                var tableSize = dt.api().rows().data().length;

                if(properties.tableSettings.currentTableSettings.freezeColumns > 1 && tableSize === 0){
                    $('.dataTables_empty').css('padding-left', '62px').text($('.dataTables_empty', dt).text())
                }
            }
```

But this is definitely not the best one.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  But I think the answer is that if you populate a row's entries w/the message you want in the the "empty table" scenario, then you'll get what you want.

Comment: Yes I've thought about it, I'm suspecting should be some build-in feature like in datatable.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the problem Issue was that fixed column also cloned padding for empty table message. If remove it then it will be fine.